# Power series $S(x):=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{{2n\choose n}}$ convergence on end points

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let's consider the real valued power series: $S_k(x):=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\frac{x^n}{{2n\choose n}}$.

I found out that the radius of convergence is $4$ or in other words $S_k(x)$ converges absolutely for each $x\in(-4,4)$. However, I am not sure if I showed correctly what happens on the end points $x=-4$ and $x=4$, respectively.

With regard to $S_k(4)$ I tried to fiddle around with the binomial theorem:

$4^n=2^{2n}=(1+1)^{2n}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n}{2n\choose i}\geq {2n\choose n}$, as ${2n\choose n}$ is always a summand of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}$. Hence, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\frac{4^n}{{2n\choose n}}\geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}1=k\implies \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\frac{4^n}{{2n\choose n}}=\infty$.

Plugging in $x=-4$, we notice that $S_k(-4)$ can't be a Cauchy sequence (which is equivalent to not being convergent in $\mathbb{R}$) because using the aboe result we get $|S_{2k+1}-S_{2k}|=\frac{4^{2k+1}}{{4k+2\choose 2k+1}}\geq1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is this correct or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we have, that if $\sum_{i\geq 0} a_i$ converges, then $a_i$ converges to zero. Hence, if you can show that the summands are not a zero sequence, the series cannot converge. The estimate $\vert 4^n/ \binom{2n}{n} \vert \geq 1$ already does the trick.

Well, in a way that is the same as you did (you just proved it from scratch).

Comment: This is faster, thank you :) I haven't thought of the zero sequence requirement.

Comment: @Philipp You're welcome :) this "criterion" is one of my favourite ones.